# How can I make Flash Video files start in the middle?

Tags: video, flv

I'd like to make Flash Video files play like YouTube - start from the middle of the video or skip to forward-spot without completing download the file.

We are not using any streaming server; we only have an HTTP server.

Can we do that like YouTube?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, provided you use one of the following techniques:

- with your webserver, apache, lighttpd, or nginx, you can install a so-called flv streaming module, see for instance http://blog.lighttpd.net/articles/2006/03/09/flv-streaming-with-lighttpd, or [mod_flvx](http://journal.paul.querna.org/articles/2006/07/11/mod_flvx/) for apache
- if you can't install such a module, you can use your favorite server-side scripting language, such as PHP, as shown in http://www.flashcomguru.com/index.cfm/2005/11/2/Streaming-flv-video-via-PHP-take-two

For this to work, your FLV files need to contain keyframes indexed in the metadata header, which you need to inject using tools such as [flvmeta](http://code.google.com/p/flvmeta/) or [flvtool2](http://rubyforge.org/projects/flvtool2/).

Then you need to use a player that supports random-access seeking, like JWPLayer or pretty much all major open-source flash video players out there, where the feature should work out-of-the-box, especially if using a server module.